# When exactly is a path-Integral equal to 0 and when to apply Cauchy's Integral formula for derivatives

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

So I am just looking at some exercise to prepare myself for the exam and just seem confused when I can apply these Theorems:

> a) Let  $A = 1 + i,  B = −1 + i, C = −1 − i, D = 1 − i$  and γ be the path [A, B, C, D, A], that is the
>   contour of the square ABCD.
>
> Compute the path Integrals $\int_{γ} \frac{e^{z}-e^{-z}}{e^{z}-4}$
>   and $\int_{γ} \frac{e^{z}}{{z}^4}$

So to the first Integral I know, that the function $f(z) =  \frac{e^{z}-e^{-z}}{e^{z}-4}$ is holomorphic and thus continous on the entire Complex plane and γ is a closed path.

> One of my Theorem only states, that if the domain is star-shaped and f is holomorphic on that domain, then f has an antiderivative. And if this is true and we are integrating over a closed curve, the Integral must be equal 0.

So why can I apply this to this example, or is there an easier way of doing it?

The second Integral can be solved with Cauchy's Integral formula for derivatives, but I am also not sure why I can apply it here?

Some explanation would help me a lot :)

Comment: Certainly $f(z)$ is *not* defined on the entire plane. There are infinitely many points $z$ for which $e^z-4=0$, after all. But are any contained inside $\gamma$? Why do you have difficulty seeing if you can apply the Cauchy integral formula (for derivatives or not)? What is the precise statement? What hypothesis or hypotheses can't you check?

Comment: Ahh that's true that it's not defined on C.  But how can you figure out, if any of these points lie within γ?

Comment: What are the solutions of $e^z = 4$?

Comment: OK, so, are any of those points on or inside $\gamma$? [Actually drawing some sketches is OK, too.]

Comment: log4+2kπi and k is an integer, so that means there outside, thus the function is holomorphic inside and on the boundary as well. Correct?

Comment: Yes, even holomorphic on an open set containing $\gamma$ and its interior ... If your hypotheses require that.

Comment: Ok I see. Well I just read this The contour integral around a simple, closed curve is 0 if the function is analytic on all of the enclosed area. So would that mean it's enough to show that it is analytic inside the area of the path and on the path? Or am I getting it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

For $$\int_{γ} \frac{e^{z}-e^{-z}}{e^{z}-4}$$ you may use the fact that the integral of a G-holomorphic function on a closed curve contained in an open region G is $0$.

For the second one  $$ \int_{γ} \frac{e^{z}}{{z}^4} $$   you may use the  Cauchy's Integral formula for  third derivatives because the function $e^z$ is an entire function.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of the first integral, you can simply use Cauchy's theorem in order to prove that it is equal to $0$, since the path is null-homotopic in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{z\in\mathbb{C}\,|\,e^z=4\}=\mathbb{C}\setminus\{\log 4+2k\pi i\,|\,k\in\mathbb Z\}$.

For the other integral, just use the residue theorem. It tells you that$$\int_\gamma\frac{e^z}{z^4}\,\mathrm dz=2\pi i\operatorname{res}_{z=0}\left(\frac{e^z}{z^4}\right)=\frac{\pi i}3.$$